# How to replace part of the string in a specific property present in all tags with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function that allows me to replace part of the content from a determined property present in several tags across the DOM.

example:

```
<a href="#" property="men-_-something-_-something">Text Here</a>
<a href="#" property="men-_-else-_-else">Text Here</a>
```

In the code above, PROPERTY is what i want to change, but only the part that says MEN, leaving the rest of the string as it is on each instance.

For the example I have used 2 instances but the real code will have close to 100 or more!

Not sure how to automate this process... any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With you help guys I have made some changes to your answers and actually sorted the puzzle! The solution is below:

```
$('a[property]').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('property');
    var val = value.split("-_-", 1);
    $(this).attr('property', value.replace(val, "women"));
});
```

This will target the property across the entire DOM and replace ONLY THE FIRST part of the string regardless of what the first part actually is... So it can be MEN, WOMEN or KIDS, and will still replace it with he right gender when needed!

Thank you guys for your help!

LEP

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure JavaScript option with RegEx:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var currentElement = elements[i].getAttribute('property');
    currentElement = currentElement.replace(/\w*/, "[the value you want to replace with]");
    elements[i].setAttribute('property', currentElement);
}
```

This will target all  elements in the DOM and change wathever string is infront of the first -.

Good luck

Zorken17

Comment: I have made a change in replace so now everytimg that is before the first - will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class to all the `a` tags

```
<a class="to-replace" href="#" property="men-_-something-_-something">Text Here</a>
<a class="to-replace" href="#" property="men-_-else-_-else">Text Here</a>
```

Then use the class name to select the elements:

```
$(".to-replace").each(function (e) {
    var val = $(this).attr("property");
    val = val.replace("men", "something else"); 
    $(this).attr("property", val); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$('a[property]').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('property'); 
    $(this).attr('property', value.replace("men-", ""));
});
```

See it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/ct7ppynz/

Comment: Hi, this actually works very simply... but I did forget an important detail which is the one giving me trouble! (my bad). This will be a single page showing items for MEN, WOMEN and KIDS, and on click will need to change to the right gender. So the string won't be MEN all the time. is it possible to use split("-_-") and somehow select the forst part of the string regardless of what it is?